# What is the algebraic equivalent to $\sum _{n=0}^xa^{-n}$?

Tags: summation

In this equation A is constant.

I am trying to convert it into an algebraic equation so I can easily solve for "x".

When I graphed it I noticed it looked like something I should be able to match to an easy function but I am unable to.

Comment: $a^{-1}=\frac{1}{a}$ are you familiar with geometric sums?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert it into an algebraic equation"? To have an equation, you have to have an "=" sign and a right-hand-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula [for the first n terms of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}cr^k = c\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Since $a^{-n} = (\frac{1}{a})^n$, we have $r = \frac{1}{a}$ and $c = 1$. So our result is $\displaystyle\frac{1-a^{-x-1}}{1-a^{-1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is your sum, then
\begin{align}
S &= a^0 + a^{-1} + a^{-2} + \cdots + a^{-x}
\\
a^{-1} S&= \qquad a^{-1} + a^{-2} + \cdots + a^{-x} + a^{-(x+1)}
\end{align}
If you subtract these two equations you get
\begin{align}
S(1-a^{-1}) &= a^0 - a^{-(x+1)}
\\
S &= \frac{1 - a^{-(x+1)}}{1-a^{-1}}
\end{align}